# Sequelize - Junction table never created

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have been trying to build a simple 'messages' app.. After giving MongoDB a try, i found out its really best to do with MySQL.

So but instead of writing all tables / queries etc by hand, I want to learn building it from the ground up with an ORM, a.k. Sequelize.

Lets say I have a user table:

```
    var User = sequelize.define('user', {
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            validate:  {
                isEmail: true
                //msg: "Email is invalid"
            }
        }
    }
```

And a message table:

```
var Message =  sequelize.define('message', {
    message: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    sender: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    read: {type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN}
}
```

Every user can have many messages, and every message can have 2 users in the conversation.

So when i do this:

```
User.hasMany(Message);
Message.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'Conversation', foreign_key: 'id'});

User.sync();
Message.sync();
```

I would expect a 'junction table' named Conversations... Holding the user_id's.. And every message having a reference to the Conversation_id, But apparently its not true...

Does anybody know what the correct way is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For create `Conversations` table you need sync all: `sequelize.sync();`.

Comment: Damn, that was easy.. But you fixed it. Thanks